# redirect add '#' after base of url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect all URLs by adding `#` after the base even if it has parameters.

**Example: (base is `http://localhost/test/`)**

```
# input
http://localhost/test/index.html
# output
http://localhost/test/#/index.html/
```

and

```
# input
http://localhost/test/dynamic/1
# output
http://localhost/test/#/dynamic/1
```

This is my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
Options -Indexes
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.html?/ [QSA,L]
```

Comment: i saw a lot of question about my problem . most of them put the same tags

Answer (score 0):

Try with below rule, before your current rules,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/#/$1 [R=301,NE]
```